# Как вернуть результат sql-запроса

Tags: javascript, node.js

Есть функция. Сервер node.js должен вернуть результат sql-запроса, но из-за асинхронной природы js у меня не получается вернуть результат через то что не успевает отработать база. До этого работал с синхронными языками у меня беда.

```
function getCollections()
{
    res = 0;
    var conn = new sql.Connection(dbConfig);
    conn.connect().then(function (recordset)
    {
        var req = new sql.Request(conn);
        req.query("SELECT * FROM Collections").then(function (recordset)
        {
            conn.close();
            res = recordset;
        })
        .catch(function (err)
        {
            console.log(err);
            conn.close();
        })
    })
    .catch(function (err)
    {
        console.log(err);
    });
    while (res === 0) { console.log(1);}
}

app.get("/", function (request, response) {    
    var res = getCollections();
    response.send(res);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша библиотека для работы с базой данных позволяет вам писать [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)-like код. Так почему бы просто не вернуть [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) из `getCollections`?

Например вот так:

```
function getCollections() {
    var conn = new sql.Connection(dbConfig);

    return conn.connect().then(function (recordset) {
        var req = new sql.Request(conn);

        return req.query("SELECT * FROM Collections").then(function (recordset) {
            conn.close();
            return Promise.resolve(recordset);
        }).catch(function (err) {
            conn.close();
            return Promise.reject(err);
        });
    });
}
```

Тогда функция обработки запроса могла бы иметь вид:

```
app.get("/", function (request, response) {    
    getCollections().then(function (records) {
        response.json(records);
    }).catch(function (error) {
        response.status(500).json({error: error.toString()});
    });
});
```

Comment: спасибо, код стал понятней!

Answer (score 1):

Закиньте response.send(res); в getCollections. Например:

```
getCollections(request, response);
```

а в `req.query("SELECT * FROM Collections").then(function (recordset)

```
  conn.close();
  res = recordset;
  response.send(res);
```

а в catch's 400

```
response.statusCode = 400;
response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
response.send(JSON.stringify({status:'error', message: 'some error'}));
```

Comment: спасибо, работает!!!

Comment: Передавая `request` и `response` в `getCollection` вы тем самым возлагаете на эту функцию лишнюю ответственность и увеличиваете зацепление (coupling).