# callback заканчивающийся не в функции в NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express

Приветствую всех, прошу посвятить

Стандартное приложение, NodeJS + ExpressJS, URL по умолчанию

```
//наш URL в браузере - http://localhost:12345/
//к нему шлем запросы
app.post('/',function(req, res){

    //объявляем переменную
    var count = 0;

    //считаем что то важное
    count = function_count_search();//sql запрос на ~20 секунд

    // .. тут оч. важные вычисления ..

    // .. а тут еще более важные вычисления ..

    //отдаем конечные данные
    res.end("~"+count+"~");
});
```

Вообщем переменная count отдается как undefined. Она отдается быстрее чем выполняется сам sql запрос. Ну конечно можно использовать калбэки! Или? Только вот в примерах из интернета в т.ч. с этого форума все примеры заканчиваются внутри функции, мне же надо что бы переменной можно было свободно оперировать, и отдать в res.end()

Такое в NodeJS можно сделать? Если да, прошу, приведите пример кода

Comment: Не дубликат, т.к. как раз указал что результат нужен НЕ в другой функции

Comment: 100% дубликат - ты хочешь получить результат из асинхронной функции, именно про это и рассказано по ссылке

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант использовать обещания.

```
function_count_search() {
   return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
   /*... Ваши вычисления ...*/ 
   resolve(count);
}
```

А в контроллере

```
app.post('/',function(req, res){

//объявляем переменную
var count = 0;

//считаем что то важное
count = function_count_search();//sql запрос на ~20 секунд

  // .. тут оч. важные вычисления ..

  // .. а тут еще более важные вычисления ..

  count.then(function(counter) {
     //отдаем конечные данные
     res.end("~"+counter +"~");
  }) 

});
```

Аналогичный вопрос был [вчера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/630910/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82-sql-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0), я отвечал что надо передавать req, res в функцию и там вызвать  res.end("~"+counter +"~");, а Dmitriy Simushev
показал вариант с обещаниями, который стал лучшим